# laravel and Jensseger MongoDB: belongsToMany not working in two directions?

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I have Laravel (v10) with [MongoDB](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).

Using e.g. `Student` and `Course` models. A student can be enrolled in multiple courses, a course can have multiple students.

When I manually enroll a student, it will add `course_ids` to the Student and `student_ids` to the Course. E.g. `Course::first()->students()->attach(Student::first());`. And then the relationship works in both directions.
BTW. Not sure why it needs two "pivot tables" that contain the same info (Course One: `student_ids: [1]` and Student John: `course_ids: [1]`).

But, I have imported the data from external source (read-only).
`Course` collection contains `student_ids`.
`Student` collection does *not* contain `course_ids`. See below.

Not sure how to get the relationships to work in two directions.

As the `Course` collection has `student_ids`, would expect I can get the students for a course, but I can only get the courses for a student.

```
Student::with('courses')->get();
// student John shows course One

Course::with('students')->get();
// course One does not show John (only student_ids: [1])
```

Question: is there a way to get this to work in both directions (without updating the collections)?
`Course::with('students')->get()`

The details:

```
# Courses (contains student_ids)
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "64cd74c98fbe694b380b3dc4"},
  "id": 1,
  "name": "One",
  "student_ids": [1]
},
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "64cd74c98fbe694b380b3dc5"},
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Two"
}
```

```
# Students (does not contain course_ids)
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "64cd74c98fbe694b380b3dc2"},
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John"
},
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "64cd74c98fbe694b380b3dc3"},
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Mary"
}
```

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded =[];

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Course::class, null, 'student_ids', 'course_ids'
        );
    }
}
```

```
class Course extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded =[];

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Student::class, null, 'course_ids', 'student_ids'
        );
    }
}
```